# How to make the scale not uniform for each small graph?

Tags: plot, julia, vega-lite

I got the graph like this with this code:
[image]

[image]

for year 2020 and 2021 I don't think they need scale up to 12000000 that high, what should I add in my code so 2020 and 2021 can scale freely without effect year 2022 graph?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A runnable example would help a lot (i.e. some sample data and code as text instead of image), but based on the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html#resolve), adding a `resolve` argument to `@vlplot` should make the Y-axis of each plot independent.

```
new |> @vlplot(:bar, 
               ...   
               resolve={scale={y="independent"}})
```